# Wrong environment in Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, environment, django-environ

[image]

I'm a beginner at Django Web Framework. At the beginning when I start Django project I didn't see `venv` folder like on the picture on the left. I didn't have `bin`, `lab` , `.gitignore` and `pyvenv.cfg` files on the right picture.

When I made new `env` I see `venv` folder but also there are duplicate bin and lib folders. All I want for now is when I start new Django project is to have one VENV folder and that it's gonna be my only enviornment and also bin and lab folders be in venv folder.

What I try is this:
That was the commands I enter on my MAC.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

That made a new env and folder `venv`. But I don't want to have another basic environment with name of the project like on the picture on the right. I don't want to have in project folder bin and lib folder also.

Comment: You do generally want to create a new virtual environment for each project. You can use a tool like poetry to make syncing your dependencies between teammates a bit easier. Creating a virtualenvironment should not create any folders outside the venv folder

Comment: lib and bin should reside inside venv dir. If they are outside then there is something wrong during its creation. Also, `.gitignore` , `pyenv.cfg` and the directory `.idea` are created by PyCharm to setup your environment (It also can create the virtualenvs)

Comment: @Niko ,By default when I starting new project,.gitignore, pyenv.cfg are outside and the name of my env is name of the project.I really dont know what happens

Comment: Instead of manually creating one, try to use PyCharm settings to [configure a virtual env](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env). Since files are not where they should be , must be some kind of confusion with paths.

Comment: I can set new enviornment but when I go to start new project all of the things are the same.....

Comment: When creating a new project, you always choose where the venv related to that project will be created, it should be `/.../my-project/venv`. Base interpreter should be your global Python.